# NULL vs DEFAULT NULL vs NULL DEFAULT NULL in MYSQL column creation?

Tags: mysql, sql

Following SQL table definition is illustrated one of create table statement from my MYSQL database which is developed by a former developer of my company.

```
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS `classifieds`.`category_vehicles`;
CREATE TABLE `classifieds`.`category_vehicles`(
`adv_id_ref` BIGINT UNSIGNED NOT NULL,
`category_id_ref` TINYINT UNSIGNED NOT NULL,
`forsale_status` TINYINT (1) NOT NULL,
`vehicle_type_id_ref` TINYINT UNSIGNED NOT NULL,
`price` DOUBLE NULL DEFAULT NULL,
 PRIMARY KEY (`adv_id_ref`)
) ENGINE = INNODB CHARSET = latin1 COLLATE = latin1_swedish_ci ;
```

In there look at the statement `price` DOUBLE NULL DEFAULT NULL,

Normally I'm using:

`price` DOUBLE NULL;

if I want to enable that column to accept NULL values.

So what are the differences between these 3 statements?

1. `price` DOUBLE NULL;
2. `price` DOUBLE DEFAULT NULL;
3. `price` DOUBLE NULL DEFAULT NULL;

Comment: You forgot one possibility... what about `price DOUBLE DEFAULT NULL NOT NULL`... i shit you not, i actually have a database defined like that :-)

Answer (score 39, accepted):

There is no difference. `NULL DEFAULT NULL` is the implicit default.

[From the CREATE TABLE documentation:](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/create-table.html#idm46972477071408)

- If neither NULL nor NOT NULL is specified, the column is treated as though NULL had been specified

[From the "Data Type Default Values" chapter:](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/data-type-defaults.html)

- If a column definition includes no explicit DEFAULT value, MySQL determines the default value as follows: If the column can take NULL as a value, the column is defined with an explicit DEFAULT NULL clause.

Answer (score 20):

```
price DOUBLE NULL;
```

`price` is a double and can be null and its default value is null.

```
price DOUBLE DEFAULT NULL;
```

`price` is a double and can be null and its default value is null.

```
price DOUBLE NULL DEFAULT NULL;
```

`price` is a double and can be null and its default value is null.

Comment: "*price is a double and cannot be null*" for the second expression is wrong. If `NULL` is omitted, `NULL` is assumed (see my quote from the manual)

Comment: @EJP to me seems like every statements are equal. I still cant extract this.  :)

Comment: @Sylar They *are* equal.

Comment: @JanacMeena 'Looking for differences when there are none' is the whole point of the answer. That's why I wrote it that way. Edit reverted.

Comment: I edited since other users also were confused by this. Up to you if you want to keep this less readable

Answer (score 1):

```
price DOUBLE NULL;
```

> Allows the `price` column to accept `NULL`.

```
price DOUBLE DEFAULT NULL;
```

> Allows the `price` column to accept `NULL` and sets the default value to `NULL`.

```
price DOUBLE NULL DEFAULT NULL;
```

> Act the same as the second statement, as it accepts `NULL` values and sets the default.